# 4th-order Runge-Kutta method for double pendulum numerical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to numerically solve the equations of motion of the double pendulum system using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method by a C++ code. 
[system diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gLjh.png) [Energy equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apKOe.png)
[required equations for the Runge-Kutta method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXCcL.png)

The problem is that my solution doesn't conserve the total energy of the system, that is after about 10 seconds of running the code there is a noticeable change of the total energy, sometimes it increases and sometimes decreases. I couldn't spot the bug that causes these undesired results.
that is the code I am using.
I referred to [myPhysicsLab.com](https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/double-pendulum-en.html) for the derivation of motion equations.

```
 void DoublePendulum::update_RK4() {
// potential energy
double potential = -(m1 + m2) * g * l1 * cos(theta1) - m2 * g * l2 * cos(theta2);

// Kinetic energy 
double kinetic = 0.5 * m1 * l1 * l1 * omega1 * omega1 + 0.5 * m2 * ((l1 * l1 * omega1 * omega1) + (l2 * l2 * omega2 * omega2) + 2 * l1 * l2 * omega1 * omega2 * cos(theta1 - theta2));

//displaying the kinetic, potential and total energy of the system.
cout << kinetic << "  " << potential << "  " << kinetic + potential << endl;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// THE NEXT 16 VARIABLES ARE THE k's of Runge-Kutta for the 4 ODEs
// All K1
double dTheta1_1 = omega1;
double dOmega1_1 = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(theta1) - m2 * g * sin(theta1 - 2 * theta2) - 2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * m2 * (pow(omega2, 2) * l2 + pow(omega1, 2) * l1 * cos(theta1 - theta2))) / (l1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)));
double dTheta2_1 = omega2;
double dOmega2_1 = (2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * (pow(omega1, 2) * l1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * cos(theta1) + pow(omega2, 2) * l2 * m2 * cos(theta1 - theta2))) / (l2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)));

// All K2
double dTheta1_2 = omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1;
double dOmega1_2 = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - m2 * g * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1)) - 2 * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1)) * m2 * (pow(omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega2_1, 2) * l2 + pow(omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega1_1, 2) * l1 * cos((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1)))) / (l1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1))));
double dTheta2_2 = omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1;
double dOmega2_2 = (2 * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1)) * (pow(omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega1_1, 2) * l1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * cos(theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) + pow(omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega2_1, 2) * l2 * m2 * cos((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1)))) / (l2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_1) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_1))));

// All K3
double dTheta1_3 = omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2;
double dOmega1_3 = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - m2 * g * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2)) - 2 * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2)) * m2 * (pow(omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega2_2, 2) * l2 + pow(omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega1_2, 2) * l1 * cos((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2)))) / (l1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2))));
double dTheta2_3 = omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2;
double dOmega2_3 = (2 * sin((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2)) * (pow(omega1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega1_2, 2) * l1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * cos(theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) + pow(omega2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dOmega2_2, 2) * l2 * m2 * cos((theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2)))) / (l2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta1_2) - 2 * (theta2 + 0.5 * stepSize * dTheta2_2))));

// All K4
double dTheta1_4 = omega1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3;
double dOmega1_4 = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - m2 * g * sin((theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - 2 * (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3)) - 2 * sin((theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3)) * m2 * (pow(omega2 + stepSize * dOmega2_3, 2) * l2 + pow(omega1 + stepSize * dOmega1_3, 2) * l1 * cos((theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3)))) / (l1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - 2 * (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3))));
double dTheta2_4 = omega2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3;
double dOmega2_4 = (2 * sin((theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3)) * (pow(omega1 + stepSize * dOmega1_3, 2) * l1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * cos(theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) + pow(omega2 + stepSize * dOmega2_3, 2) * l2 * m2 * cos((theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3)))) / (l2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * (theta1 + stepSize * dTheta1_3) - 2 * (theta2 + stepSize * dTheta2_3))));


double theta1New = theta1 + (stepSize / 6.0) * (dTheta1_1 + 2 * dTheta1_2 + 2 * dTheta1_3 + dTheta1_4);
double omega1New = omega1 + (stepSize / 6.0) * (dOmega1_1 + 2 * dOmega1_2 + 2 * dOmega1_3 + dOmega1_4);
double theta2New = theta2 + (stepSize / 6.0) * (dTheta2_1 + 2 * dTheta2_2 + 2 * dTheta2_3 + dTheta2_4);
double omega2New = omega2 + (stepSize / 6.0) * (dOmega2_1 + 2 * dOmega2_2 + 2 * dOmega2_3 + dOmega2_4);


// updating variables 
theta1 = theta1New;
omega1 = omega1New;
theta2 = theta2New;
omega2 = omega2New;
```

}

Comment: Runge-Kutta methods are not conservative, this is expected behaviour. Decreasing the step-size will slow the rate of energy dissipation, but to conserve energy you need specific solvers (symplectic methods).

Comment: Thanks, @David. I used a step size of 0.01 second and there was about 0.5 Joule difference in the total energy after each iteration.
Did you read the code and found it correct?

Comment: I didn't check it, your results were not unexpected though. You can always check it by solving a few ODEs with solutions you know.

Comment: Even with symplectic solvers it is expected that the exact energy oscillates, the advantage is just that the amplitude of that oscillation grows much slower than in non-symplectic methods of the same order. However, in RK4 you should get results that have the same error order as the second order Verlet method using the same step size. // What is the total energy, that is, what is the relative size of the error you observe? // Your code is almost unreadable, which is usually bad for debugging and maintainance, but there do not appear to be any obvious or typical errors.